# Up to Date - Zip Code Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, zipcode

I've been using the zipcode information from here:

http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2010.html

in my mySQL database but I've noticed that it's missing quite a few zipcodes

(ex. 94142, San Francisco, CA)

....does anyone know of some more up to date zip code data?

Comment: Thanks Everyone! +1 for all...

Comment: This one seems pretty good: http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/download.html

Answer (score 18):

Try the data at http://www.geonames.org/

(There's a Free postal Code Data link there, with postal codes for lots of countries).

Comment: Useful!  The site provides a text file that can be downloaded and easily converted to other formats like CSV using Excel.

Comment: this one does not have complete AK.HI,PR zipcode...

Comment: It also only lists one city per zipcode.  In many cases there are multiple cities in the same zipcode.  Where can I get that data?

Answer (score 8):

The United States Postal Service is the government entity that provisions ZIP codes.  As such, the authoritative, always-correct database is theirs.

Happily, they provide free APIs that developers can use:

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm

Comment: The terms & conditions of using the USPS API exclude any use other than to facilitate USPS shipping. So, by the terms of the agreement, you aren't supposed to use the API for, let's say, a moving company quote calculator (one example of many).

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the Census Bureau doesn't have all ZIP Codes is because they only contain the ones with populations (general delivery addresses) and don't contain ZIPs for PO Boxes.

Answer (score 2):

I get mine zip codes, and more, from [here](http://www.zip-codes.com). This also includes latitude and longitude information, which makes calculating distances between locations possible.